# Perl date function/module able to understand full unabbreviated months

Tags: perl, date, module

Let's say I read in a string from somewhere that contains a date, and it's date format doesn't abbreviate the month.  Is there a module that can handle reading it in, and then outputting it to whichever format I choose?  I've taken a quick look through CPAN, and every date module I looked at didn't seem to accommodate an unabbreviated month.

Thanks for any help

EDIT:
As an example, say we have a string like this; "2 February 1988".  Now we want to convert it into "1988-02-02" (YYYY-MM-DD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`DateTimeX::Easy`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTimeX%3a%3aEasy):

### Program

```
my $dt = DateTimeX::Easy->new('2 February 1988');
print $dt->date();
```

### Output

```
1988-02-02
```

Comment: Wow, that's a nice module; I can stop writing my own code to try to handle input from unknown sources.

Answer (score 6):

You can utilize core [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aPiece) module and its `strptime` method. The format is described on [strftime man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/), for full month name there is `%B` format specifier:

```
use Time::Piece;
my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime("2 February 1988", "%d %B %Y");
print $dt->ymd,"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use Date::Parse, since it can automatically detect the input format and convert it to unix time with "str2time". If I then want to format the date I use "strftime".

```
use Date::Parse;
use POSIX 'strftime';

$unix_time = str2time "2 February 1988";
print strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime $unix_time;
```

Comment: You probably forgot `strftime` after `print` on last line. The example does not work as it is.

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry. Works now.

Answer (score -1):

You should write your own conversion module.

You can use hashes to do quick conversions like this:

my %month = ("Jan" => "01",
            "Feb" => "02",
            "Mar" => "03",
            "Apr" => "04",
            "May" => "05",
            "Jun" => "06",
            "Jul" => "07",
            "Aug" => "08",
            "Sep" => "09",
            "Oct" => "10",
            "Nov" => "11",
            "Dec" => "12");

my %day = ("Sun" => "01",
            "Mon" => "02",
            "Tue" => "03",
            "Wen" => "04",
            "Thu" => "05",
            "Fri" => "06",
            "Sat" => "07");

Comment: Yes, you're right, I could do that, but someone else must have come across this problem before me.  Anyway, before I roll my own, I'd like to see if the community knows of an already built module.

Comment: CPAN should be the first thing to think of.. NOT to write own code.. in general with Perl and especially with date related questions as there are one phantastizillion modules for that.